# Was Fisher's disapproval of Barnard's test really "specious", as mentioned on Wikipedia?

Tags: history

The [Wikipedia article on Barnard's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnard%27s_test) currently says:

> While first published in 1945 by G.A. Barnard, the test did not
> gain popularity due to the computational difficulty of calculating the
> p value and **Fisher’s specious disapproval**.

Following some comments under [this other question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/631675/besides-barnards-test-what-are-some-examples-of-statistical-methods-that-have), I'm wondering if the wikipedia article is incorrect relative to this "Fisher's specious disapproval".

Comment: See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/364443/17230) for an overview of the issues involved, & [Choi et al. (2015) "Elucidating the Foundations of Statistical Inference with 2 x 2 Tables", *PLoS ONE*, **10**, 4](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0121263) for a detailed account of them. Fisher's objections oughtn't to be dismissed as "specious", whether you agree with them or not. (Barnard came to agree with them: [Barnard (1949), "Statistical Inference", *J.R.Stat.Soc. B*, **11**, 2](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2984075).)

Comment: The Wikipedia entry also states: "Under specious pressure from Fisher, Barnard retracted his test in a published paper ...." The word 'specious' was added in October 2021 by a nameless contributor. How insulting to Barnard to imply that a highly-respected statistician like Barnard would reject his own published test without good reason. It's clear he preferred Fisher's conditional test to his own test because conditioning provided a more relevant reference set.